# Aggregate Data Frame After Using Pandas Grouped Map UDF - Java Error

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions, pyarrow

My pyspark environment:

- AWS EMR release label 6.1.0
- Spark 3.0.0
- Pandas 1.1.0
- Pyarrow 0.15.1
- Python 3.7.16

I am troubleshooting this error in a Jupyter Notebook attached to my cluster.

I have a dataframe called my_df that I am passing to a Pandas Grouped Map function called my_function, which is created using my_schema.

```
@pandas_udf(my_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_function(my_df):
   *do stuff*
   return my_df
```

I am calling my_function in this way:

```
my_df_new = (my_df.drop('some_column').groupby('some_other_column').apply(my_function))
```

With the returned my_df_new, I create a temporary view and use spark sql to query it. `select * from my_df_new` returns results successfully, but when I try to aggregate, like `select count(*) from my_df_new`, it throws the java error at bottom.

Here is what I've tried to fix this to no avail:

- Altering the spark session with the following configurations:

  - "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "0"
  - "spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled": "true"
  - "spark.sql.execution.pandas.udf.buffer.size": "2000000000"
  - "spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch": "33554432"
- Updating pyarrow to 1.0.1 and 12.0.0

I don't know what else to try. Anyone have any ideas?

```
An error occurred while calling o147.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 151 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 151.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 14659, ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.my_domain.com, executor 47): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 0, length: 1073741824 (expected: range(0, 0))
    at io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf.checkIndex(ArrowBuf.java:716)
    at io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf.setBytes(ArrowBuf.java:954)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.reallocDataBuffer(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:508)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.handleSafe(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:1239)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.BaseVariableWidthVector.setSafe(BaseVariableWidthVector.java:1066)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.StringWriter.setValue(ArrowWriter.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowFieldWriter.write(ArrowWriter.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrayWriter.setValue(ArrowWriter.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowFieldWriter.write(ArrowWriter.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowWriter.write(ArrowWriter.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:90)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1932)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:218)
```

Comment: When you `select * from my_df_new` returns results successfully, how many rows that you're trying to show?

Comment: I've only been showing the top 20 rows

Comment: Is the issue caused by the UDF?

Comment: How did u change `spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch` config?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a bug / edge case in your UDF `my_function` when you handle array-like data structure. Based on the error traceback that you provide, the index that you used to access the array exceeds the length and cause the error. You can try to test a simple UDF first, like return the first element if the length of array is greater than 1 else return `None`, and do both `select * from my_df_new` and `select count(*) from my_df_new` to see if there is any other issues.

When you do the aggregation based on the previous transformed data frame and take the action (`.show()`), like `select count(*) from my_df_new` in your example, it will apply the UDF to all your RDD. As Spark is lazy evaluated, the bug / edge case error will be trigger at this moment.